# TeX tutorial too intimidating/extensive

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

The help sidebar ("How to format") links to http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/

[image]

That's a bit *too* extensive for us. (And it's for LaTeX proper, not mathjax so it has tons of irrelevant stuff)

Can we please write our own tutorial? (Or link to [this proposed faq section](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/81/22)?)

One of my friends told me she was intimidated by it and would read it when she had enough time--whereas TeX doesn't take *that* much time to learn the basics.

I am open to writing the tutorial myself.

Edit: [Tada!](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/22)

Comment: Yeah, if you're open to it, then do it! At least get started; then others can chip in as needed. You might start here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117

Comment: @Shog9 ooh thanks! We don't have math on meta so I'll do it on a personal server. Also, I'll have to write a bit on mhchem. I'll get to it soon...

Comment: @Shog9 actually, could we have math+mhchem on meta? I'd prefer writing the post in markdown than HTML. (Otherwise I'll just write a few regexes to convert backticks to codeblocks and the like)

Comment: Sure - this stuff happens on an as-needed basis; if you post [at least a short] tutorial that requires it, I'll get it enabled.

Comment: @Shog, Alrighty, I'll post a tutorial... At least a part of it.

Comment: @Shog9: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/22 It's halfway done (all the important stuff is there, though). I'll let you know when I finish it so that you can add it to the editor help.

Comment: @Shog9: [Finished](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/22) (pretty much, I may think of improvements but it's complete in itself now). Could you enable mathjax and switch the editor link over to this? (Also a [faq] tag would be nice.)

Comment: @Shog9: Could you update the MathJax link in the "How To Format" sidebar now? I think the tutorial is complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

MathJax is now enabled on the meta site as well.

$\LaTeX$