# Additional note on "Markdown Editing Help"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Yesterday I extended one of my answers.  Hosted on the chemistry site, chemical equations were used, yet it was rather by accident I recognized the option to use LaTeX's [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/) environment \ce{} inside the mathematical mode.  An inline reaction equation (like this following $\ce{2 H2 + O2 -> H2O}$) written with the \ce{}-environment is a lot easier written and maintained than in "mathematical only" mode (like $2\, \mathrm{H}_2 + \mathrm{O} \rightarrow \mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}$).  Yet these examples do not cover advanced features mhchem eases to input like presence of charges like $\ce{Na+}$ viz. $\mathrm{Na}^+$.

Therefore this suggestion, to add a note on the corresponding [markdown editing help page](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) that states its existence and briefly demonstrates a minimal working example.

Comment: All sites Exchange-wide have recently moved from a "faq" based help to the [Help].  We will look into incorporating the information into that for everyone's reference.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Note that [a help center page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for this already exists, it's just not so visible

Comment: Great pickup! I'ma test it now: $\ce{H2O}$

Answer (score 6):

I'll just see if I can draft the contents of a new section here:

> #### LaTeX
>
> We support most LaTeX math commands, as well as the `\ce{}` extension
>   from the `mhchem` package. Just enclose your TeX code with `$ ... $`
>   (for inline math), or `$$ ... $$` (if you want it centered on its own
>   line) and it will render. If you wish to use chemical formulae or
>   equations, simply use the `ce{}` macro around the
>
> ```
> Here is some inline math $\sqrt{x+1}$
> Here is some block level math $$\frac{1}{x+1}$$
> $\ce{H2O}$ is the chemical formula for water
> ```
>
> For more information, please see [this TeX tutorial](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88)