# Which symbols are written in roman (upright) font and which are italicized?

Tags: discussion

This post tries to be a guide to new members of the (chemical) scientific community for instructions on how to apply the right formatting when writing chemical and mathematical equations.

Comment: As a heavy editor myself, I am absolutely pro nice typeset. So while I see a post that needs redo, I try to go the whole ten yards, i.e. also changing all `\times` to `\cdot`. Whenever I review an edit that contains these faulty typesets I will improve it. When I see some faulty typeset in a post, but it is still very much understandable, I usually leave it that way (some people just refuse to use mhchem and then roll back). I think a good typeset is important for future references, so it should be done.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン In many cases, changing `\times` to `\cdot` may be acceptable, preferable, or even absolutely necessary; however _“if the point is used as the decimal sign, the cross and not the half-high dot should be used as the multiplication sign between numbers expressed with digits.”_ $4\,711.32 \times 0.351\,2$

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Which symbols are written in roman (upright) font?**

*As a rule of thumb: Symbols representing physical quantities or mathematical variables are the only things written in italic type.*

### Guidelines

Everything of the following is *not* written in italics:

- Unit symbols, e.g. $\mathrm{kg}$, $\mathrm{kJ}$, $\mathrm{mol}$, $\mathrm{K}$
- Chemical formulae. These are written in roman font automatically when using the `mhchem` commands, i.e. `$\ce{...}$`.
- Function names such as $\sin$, $\cos$, $\log$, i.e. `\sin`, `\cos`, `\log`. (MathJax recognizes standard mathematical function names and automatically applies the correct style to them.)
- Mathematical constants, the values of which never change, e.g. $\mathrm{e} = 2.718\,218\,8\ldots$, $\mathrm {i}^2 = -1$
  (Note that this convention for $\mathrm e$ and $\mathrm i$ is recommended by ISO 80000, IUPAC, NIST, and ACS, but italicizing these expressions is also very common.)
- Descriptive indices such as $_\text{ox}$, $_\text{red}$ or $_\text{tot}$
- Descriptive text
- Symbols for mathematical operators, e.g. $\Delta$ in $\Delta x=x_2-x_1$ and each $\mathrm d$ in $\mathrm df/\mathrm dx$ (derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$). Note that $x$ and $y$ are variables in this context.
  (Note that this convention for differentials and derivatives is recommended by ISO 80000, IUPAC, NIST, and ACS; it is also used in the rules and style conventions presented in *The International System of Units* (SI). Nevertheless, italicizing these expressions is also very common.)
- Electronic configurations $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^4}$

Everything of the following *is* written in italics:

- Symbols representing physical quantities, e.g. $m$ for mass or $V$ for volume,
  including fundamental physical constants (quantities that are considered to be constant under all circumstances), e.g. Planck constant $h$, Faraday constant $F$
- Mathematical variables, e.g. $x$ and $y$, including expressions such as “the $x$ axis”
- Iterative variables such as $i$ in a sum
- Parameters, such as $a$, $b$, etc., which may be considered as constant in a particular context
- Locants in chemical-compound names indicating attachments to heteroatoms, e.g. *N*,*N*-dimethylaniline
- Stereochemical descriptors as (*E*) or (*Z*)

Subscripts:

When, in a given context, different quantities have the same letter symbol or when, for one quantity, different applications or different values are of interest, a distinction can be made by use of subscripts. The following principles for the printing of subscripts apply (see also specific heat capacity $c_p$ in "Examples" below).

- A subscript that represents a physical quantity or a mathematical variable, such as a running number, is printed in italic type, e.g. equilibrium constant on a pressure basis $K_p$ and equilibrium constant on a concentration basis $K_c$.
- Other subscripts, such as those representing words or fixed numbers, are printed in upright type, e.g. Avogadro constant $N_\mathrm A$.

There are of course some mixed notations possible:

- Chemical formulae which contain variables, such as the $n$ in the general formula for alkanes ($\ce{C_{$n$}H_{$2n+2$}}$) or $x$ in this molecular formula for a superconductor: $\ce{LaO_{$1−x$}F_{$x$}FeAs}$
- Point groups, for example $C_n$, $S_{2n}$, $D_n$, $D_{n\mathrm{h}}$, $D_{n\mathrm{d}}$, $C_{n\mathrm{v}}$, $C_{n\mathrm{h}}$, $T$, $T_\mathrm{h}$, $T_\mathrm{d}$, $O$, $O_\mathrm{h}$, $I_\mathrm{h}$, $C_{\infty\mathrm{v}}$, $D_{\infty\mathrm{h}}$. More detail can be found in the question on the main site: [How are point group character tables typeset correctly?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32894/)
- The symbol $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ for the logarithmic acid dissociation constant (read details under "Examples")

## How do I do this?

There are two generic commands that produce roman output, `\text{}` and `\mathrm{}`.
The main difference between the two commands is the way how math command characters such as the caret **^** or the underline **_** are interpreted. In `\text{}` these get rendered out literally and in `\mathrm{}` they get interpreted as usual. The use of `\mathrm{}` is therefore recommended. *(The command `\rm` should be avoided since it is [deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151897/33413) and only maintained for backwards compatibility.)*

The `mhchem` extension offers two shortcuts, `\ce` and `\pu`.

### Display Math and inline Math

There are several possibilities to typeset mathematical formulae.
The inline math mode is invoked by bracing the statement with dollar signs, i.e. `$...$`.
A displayed mathematical equation, it is centered and typeset a little bigger, can be invoked using double dollar signs as braces, i.e. `$$...$$`. Here it is also possible to force a line break with `\\`.
When dealing with more than one equation, an aligning environment should be used instead, i.e. `\begin{align}...\end{align}`. The alignment character is the `&`. This can also be used in conjunction with the `\ce{...}` statements.

## Examples

- Chemical formulae and equations:  `$$\ce{H2O + HCl <--> H3O+ + Cl-}$$` becomes $$\ce{H2O + HCl <--> H3O+ + Cl-}$$
- Units: `$$E = 33.4~\mathrm{kJ\, mol^{-1}}$$` becomes $$E = 33.4~\mathrm{kJ\, mol^{-1}}$$
  Note that there is a tilde character between the numbers and the `\mathrm{}` command, which produces a fixed, non-linebreaking space.
  Or: `$$E = \pu{123E6 kJ mol-1}$$` becomes $$E = \pu{123E6 kJ mol-1}$$
- Sums and descriptive text: `$$m_\text{tot} = \sum_i^N m_i ~\text{for}~N~\text{substances}$$` becomes $$m_\text{tot} = \sum_i^N m_i ~\text{for}~N~\text{substances}$$
- Specific heat capacity $c_p$: Here the subscript denotes the constant pressure $p$ and is as such written in italics; whereas in the molar heat capacity at constant pressure $C_{\mathrm m,p}$, the subscript $\mathrm m$ does not represent a quantity but the adjective “molar” and is printed in roman (upright) type.
- In the symbol $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ for the logarithmic acid dissociation constant, the roman symbol $\mathrm p$ is interpreted as an operator ($\mathrm px=-\lg x$), the italic symbol $K$ represents a quantity (the dissociation constant), and the roman subscript $\mathrm a$ represents the word “acid”.
- Locants: *O*-ethyl hexanethioate; *N*-methylbenzamide
- Electronic configurations can easily be written using the `mathrm` command. The MathJaX command `\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^6 (3s)^1}` renders as $$\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^6 (3s)^1}\,.$$ Alternatively you can use `\mathrm{[Ne] (3s)^1}` to get $$\mathrm{[Ne] (3s)^1}\,.$$
- Stereochemical descriptors are preferably italicized through markdown `(*E*)` or `(*Z*)`, and not mathjax

---

Sources / Further reading:

- ISO/IEC: [ISO/IEC 80000 Quantities and units (14 parts)](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=46202)
- BIPM: [The International System of Units (SI)](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/)
- IUPAC: [Quantities, Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry (Green Book) 2011](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IUPAC-GB3-2012-2ndPrinting-PDFsearchable.pdf)
- NIST: [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)](http://www.nist.gov/pml/pubs/sp811/)
- ACS: [The ACS Style Guide](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG)
- Related question on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33120/should-subscripts-in-math-mode-be-upright)

Comment: For solid state chemistry, is there any consensus on writing fcc, *fcc* or FCC?

Comment: @Apurvium ACS recommends fcc, [IUCr](https://www.iucr.org/resources/commissions/crystallographic-nomenclature/bravais) — *cF*. I have no authoritative recommendation for FCC, and *fcc* makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: @andselisk What if "text" is a descriptive variable/quantity name that should be ( at least generally) in italic? Or if a variable/quantity name has multiple letters (explained in context /legend), so $ROD$ is intended to mean the variable ROD and not $R \cdot O \cdot D$? Should be quoting involved for the former? // Should be descriptive/multiletter variable/quantity names upright or italic? // For context, see [CH SE question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162130/writing-rate-of-disappearance-and-rate-of-appearance-using-rate-law) and its comments.

Comment: @Poutnik Multiple-letter abbreviations for variables are always upright and should *not* be used in math expressions, only in prose. OTOH, mathematical symbols that are generally only one letter (optionally with sub-/superscript(s)) can be used both in text and math expressions. ACS Style Guide 2006, p. 211: "*For example, in text with no equations, $\mathrm{PE}$ for potential energy is acceptable, but in mathematical text and equations, $E_\mathrm{p}$ is preferred.*" Buttonwood rightfully criticizes improper $ROD$ expression which reads as product of three one-letter variables $R$, $O$, $D.$

Comment: @andselisk I see, good to know. I have asked because I have not found clear guidance above ( text versus variable ). I guess if some abbreviation is official, like e.g. BOD ( biological oxygen demand ) then it can be exceptionally used in expressions, but upright.