# A link to common notation and symbols on the Tour page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, design

Most new joiners do not know about the tools for mathematical and chemical formatting provided by Chemistry.SE.

The [Tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) details out the core concept of asking questions very well, but I feel the need to this link on the [tools](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) used here is needed as new-comers usually bump out here with questions.

Usually, the higher rep users have to edit their questions and give them the link in the comments for proper presentation.

Hence a mention on the Tour page would be helpful. Wouldn't it?

Comment: "Visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation "LaTex at chemistry.SE") to ‎find out how to make your future posts better.‎" Yes, that's what I tell them to do. The problem is, some don't even bother to do so!

Comment: There is another problem. We have to have a special kind of tour page, and that isn't happening until site graduation. Some users are familiar with LaTex, but don't know about `mhchem`, or don't know that they can make use of it.

Comment: @MARamezani No need for a new kind of tour page , they just need to add a statement containing the link under "Improve posts by editing or commenting" section. Or right under the "Ask Questions "  heading.

Comment: They're too lazy for that. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly, it would do no harm if the introduction for new users links to the available tools. However, I am afraid that the proposal does not help either.

Users usually do not read the guidelines given in the [Tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help); they read existing questions and answers. Therefore, new posts tend to adapt to the quality of existing posts.

Even if (new as well as well-established) users know the tools, they mostly do not really know what to do with them since they do not know how to properly write quantities, units, and equations. That is why many posts look terrible or are simply wrong. (I suppose, many comprehension problems when using quantity equations are related to this.)

Hence, in order to be useful and effective, any introduction to the available tools would also have to include the relevant contents of the [SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/), the [ISO 80000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_80000), and the applicable [IUPAC color books](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/color-books/). For example, [this answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-we-correct-math-formatting/444#444) could be a good start.

Therefore, any introduction should not only present the available tools, but also explain what to do with them. Or, better still, the other way round: The introduction should first state the requirements for quantities, units, and equations and then show how these requirements can be fulfilled with the available tools.