# Poll: mhchem syntax for electron configuration

Tags: discussion, mhchem

As the author of mhchem, I am considering to add electron configuration to `\ce`. I decided to give it a little bit spacing for readability: $\mathrm{[Kr]\mskip2mu4d^{10}\mskip2mu5s^1\mskip2mu5p^3\mskip2mu5d^4}$.

Now, I'd like to ask you what you consider an intuitive input syntax.
I will propose some answers, please vote.

Disclaimer: This is no promise that this feature will come or that I will implement the winning syntax. In fact, it might even be impossible to use a certain syntax because of side-effects.

Comment: I would consider not including it in the `\ce` command, but a different command since it enhances readability of the code.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I would never have the idea if `\ce` were not already used that way, here at SE. So I want to support it properly (and with a recommended syntax, although I might support more).

Comment: ... several hundred times.

Comment: Yes, probably because it is easier to sub- and superscript numbers this way instead of using html tags. In a pure tex setting I would probably go a different route. Nevertheless, it is wonderful how you take care of us; thank you.

Comment: I agree for the LaTeX only setting, where users are used to have specialized commands. For SE (and therefore MathJax/mhchem) I would tend to go for the design principle of [desire lines](http://www.doctordisruption.com/design/principles-of-design-50-desire-lines/). // While we are at it, I don't like the output of `\ce` sticking out from the surrounding text when this is not necessary (e.g. just subscripts and superscripts). But changing that would need a major effort of the MathJax core guys or of SE.

Comment: This is indeed a good idea, especially for MathJax. LaTeX is a lot more flexible to be customised, you can choose your own path there. // The sticking out part of MathJax has become a lot better when we got our own design, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/1673/4945) for some discussion. Previously some user tried to circumvent this by using for example`H$_2$SO$_4$`, which is awkward, because the formula might break at a line end. And since you cannot predict those accurately (esp. mobile) this is a problem for readability. Currently I am quite happy with what it looks like.

Comment: Regarding font, [I could not resist](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3589/24052).

Answer (score 23):

In order to get $\mathrm{[Kr]\mskip2mu4d^{10}\mskip2mu5s^1\mskip2mu5p^3\mskip2mu5d^4}$, I'd prefer to input `$\ce{[Kr] 4d10 5s1 5p3 5d4}$`.

Comment: Legible both in code and result. Clean and easy. I like it!

Comment: Would it be easier from a parsing perspective to move the orbital population notation inside the square bracket in the markup? e.g., `$\ce{[Kr 4d10 5s1 5p3 5d4]}$`? Obviously it would still be rendered with only the element symbol bracketed.

Comment: @hBy2Py Parsing would be easier. But the philosophy of mhchem is not about easy parsing but about intuitive input.

Comment: This is how users type it when using text-only input [ex. 1](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/64346/1), [ex. 2](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/68607/1)

Answer (score 11):

In order to get $\mathrm{[Kr]\mskip2mu4d^{10}\mskip2mu5s^1\mskip2mu5p^3\mskip2mu5d^4}$, I'd prefer to input `$\ce{[Kr] 4d^10 5s^1 5p^3 5d^4}$`.

Comment: This gets my second vote as an acceptable alternative.

Comment: [Seen in the wild](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/64346/3) (because you get acceptable results, that way).

Comment: Already used a few dozen times here at SE (when including `4d^{10}`).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get $\mathrm{[Kr]\mskip2mu4d^{10}\mskip2mu5s^1\mskip2mu5p^3\mskip2mu5d^4}$, I'd prefer to input `$\ce{[Kr]4d^{10}5s^15p^35d^4}$`.

Comment: This is how some users intuitively write things.  `$\mathrm{1s^22s^22p^63s^1}$` [source](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68375/24052)

Answer (score -7):

In order to get $\mathrm{[Kr]\mskip2mu4d^{10}\mskip2mu5s^1\mskip2mu5p^3\mskip2mu5d^4}$, I'd prefer to input `$\ce{[Kr]4d105s15p35d4}$`.

Comment: Dear God, please no.

Comment: The problem is both readability and discoverability. No search engine is going to interpret that as 4d10 5s1 etc.

Comment: The search engine argument is not correct. Try Google, Google Books, Bing with the search term 1s22s22p63s23p6. (BTW, I don't like that syntax either.)