# What does "We are no longer accepting questions from this account" mean?

Tags: support, question-answer-ban

Why am I getting this notification "we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?

Comment: Related FAQ on meta: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/271002)

Comment: How many questions have you asked on this site, previously? Have you deleted some of them?

Comment: @Rubisco i have asked only 2 questions and one was deleted long long ago

Comment: What was its score? You should edit and improve it.

Comment: @Rubisco it was -1 most probably...it was based on stochiometry and I agree that it lacked proper effort..

Comment: @Rubisco I cant even find it now ... but just for one question i should be banned that too the question i asked half year ago ...really unfair of SE to do so

Comment: Yours is a strange case. People do get question-banned, but it's usually two or three **heavily** downvoted questions, i.e. around -5 or lower. I don't think a ban should've been put in place here, especially considering that your new question has a positive score.

Comment: The other possibility is that OP shares an IP address with someone who was legitimately question banned, I suppose. I've been banned from Wikipedia edits before because of that.

Comment: It says that I would gave to wait for 2 days before reasking

Comment: Is it ok if i Create a new account and access?

Comment: @Rubisco is it okay if i create a new account and ask?

Comment: You have asked four questions, three of them deleted and two of them closed. None of these had a positive score. 10k+: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50723/4945 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50696/4945 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50652/4945

Comment: No, it's not okay to bypass a ban with creating a new account. @Mart it would be appreciated if you answer and elaborate on how the OP can improve their questions, if they can. (or any 10k'er, for that matter)

Answer (score 7):

Everything relevant to this message can be found here: 
[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/260760)

As for your account, you have asked four questions some of them not very well received by the community.
On one occasion I even made you aware of this:

> I am personally against closing any question because of a wrong premise (cc @ringo). That being said, the question is unclear to me - it is not even a complete sentence. When you state that you did *adequate research*, then please include your efforts, so no-one has to repeat the process that did not yield results. However, welcome to Chemistry.SE! I **strongly recommend** taking the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Your questions have not been received very well so far, so I **recommend** that you also review our [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/). – Martin - マーチン♦ May 6 at 6:21

You should try to fix them, by improving them and undeleting them. Since you might not be able to find them, here are the links (10k+):

- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50723/4945 (c, d, -4)
- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50696/4945 (c, d, 0)
- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50652/4945 (c, d, -1)

It's easy enough to fix some/ one of those. Please read our [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) so that you know how. You should also take the [tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour).

Here are a few tips: Choose a meaningful title. [Don't use buzzwords](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583/4945), including the word 'doubt'. Proofread your post for spelling errors. Note that a comma, colon, full stop, etc. follows immediately after the word and is succeeded by a space; not the other way around. Use some basic formatting; have a look [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945).

Also be aware that commenting something like 'Please answer my question.' might lead to more down votes. If you do your part, we do ours.

Do not try to work around the ban with a new account, if you do not follow the guidelines, it will get the same ban earlier.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this answer, Mart. One thing though . . . He got the ban after a new question with a +1 score, and no downvotes. Why would that happen?

Comment: @rubi uh. I don't know that. The user might have been asking another question while the now upvoted one was still at zero. Then again this is just a theory and I wouldn't know how to check this. Anyway, the ban lasts only for two days, as far as I can see.