# What is the standard LaTeX depiction of G "naught"?

Tags: discussion, formatting

A user today wrote $G^0$ (`G^0`) to indicate standard Gibbs energy. I quickly edited it to $G^\circ$ (`G^\circ`) instead as that's the notation I'm used to more.

However, then I realized an intriguing fact. Whenever I speak $G^\circ$ (in English at least) I say it as "G naught". I don't call it "G circle" or "G not" instead. The word "naught" in English means "nill", "nothing", or, well, **"zero"**!

Thus, based on its mode of speaking, it makes more sense to write `G^0` than `G^\circ`.

This has not been [covered before](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/444/5026) so I am asking it now. I checked the [green book](https://www.iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Green-Book-PDF-Version-2011.pdf) but couldn't find "Latex depiction of thermodynamics symbols" or any related topic.

> What is the standard LaTeX depiction of `G^0`? And sister symbols like `E^0`...?

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, it is a perfectly valid meta question.

Comment: @Jan probably because of this https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/are-questions-being-excessively-edited/4169#4169

Answer (score 6):

The standard state is indicated by the standard state sign (not available in standard LaTeX), or a circle, as recommended in Green Book 2.11.1 (ii) p.60:

[image: Green book 2.11.1 (ii) p.60 (screenshot)]

**It is definitely not a zero, naught, nill, oh, ... .** In absence of any of these symbols, one should resort to specifying parameters in parentheses ($G(\pu{273.15 K})$), or for what it's worth, $G(\text{std.})$ might be acceptable, too.

I personally have neither used nor heard the term G "naught", to me precise language matters, ergo: standard Gibbs energy/ standard free energy.

Comment: "I personally have neither used nor heard the term G "naught"" Intriguing! So, if you were to speak the equation $\Delta G^\circ=-RT\ln K$ aloud, would you read "delta standard G" or "delta G naught"? Am asking because in our class we always did the latter :P

Comment: @GaurangTandon when we're all looking at the same page: Delta G is sufficient I think, otherwise: Delta G (at) standard (conditions), in written form: just the symbol, or the energy difference in the standard free energy.