# Spreading awareness about using \ce{....}

Tags: discussion, formatting

I have seen most of the question without \ce{...}. I don't know why user don't use that. Might be they are not aware about that because it is not used in other S.E.

So how to aware users about it I think best way to make new user aware is, to put that in **formatting help** box.

Comment: The best way is to edit it in thoroughly and leave a comment under their post, like I did [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/show-proposed-mechanism-is-consistent-with-the-experimental-rate-law#comment24435_15850)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as *asking* goes, there's  a link to MathJax help on the sidebar:

[image]

which links to [this tutorial](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88#88)

However, it's a bit hidden. In the past, I've found that linking people to that page in comments helps immensely — I used to go around mhchem-ifying posts and then leaving comments to teach the new users how to do it themselves (having an example in front of you helps)

Comment: This isn't available on Android browsers or the App.

Answer (score 4):

I think the approach that Martin proposes in the comment above is really the most practical:

> The best way is to edit it in thoroughly and leave a comment under their post, like I did [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/show-proposed-mechanism-is-consistent-with-the-experimental-rate-law#comment24435_15850)

I'm optimistic that our core users can use this "teach a man to fish approach" for most cases.

The editing help (accessible via the golden question mark at the upper right corner of any question or answer textbox, then via "Advanced Help"/"LaTeX")

[image]

talks about formatting $\LaTeX$, but it doesn't really go into the mhchem particulars.  I think we had talked about getting some more detailed instructions into the editing help, but I think it was decided that we would have a separate page in the *site* help, which can be found at:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

We can revisit getting it into the editing help, but I think the above link along with the gentle reminders for new users should do the trick in most cases.

Comment: I wouldn't have noticed the implementation of mhchem, if I wasn't made aware of this via a comment - it is quite hidden. Most users react quite friendly with a "thank you" and start using it for the next questions/ answers. (Only a few are too stubborn, lol.)