# How to solve mhchem/MathJax rendering problems

Tags: discussion, mathjax, mhchem, formatting

> **Edit**: This is not a bug, it is a feature, see my answer post.

While recently directing a new user to [this meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88#88) about formatting using MathJax, I noticed that some components were not rendering correctly.

For example, The bond between $\ce{E}$ and $\ce{F}$ is typeset very strangely.
$$\ce{H\bond{->}A-B=C#D\bond{~}E\bond{~-}F\bond{...}G\bond{<-}E}$$

In the next example, the equilibrium arrows are broken, and the subscripts are placed too low:
$$\ce{H2O + HCl<=>H3O+ + Cl-}$$

Here is an image for reference once the problem is fixed:

[image: image showing broken mhchem typesetting]

The issue appears to only be for rendering certain items using the `mhchem` environment, and it is **only on meta**. Rendering works fine on main, see image:

[image: An image showing correct mhchem rendering on main]

Comment: I changed it to [tag:discussion] since it is a browser setting and we don't want the community mods come down here for no reason.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

So, after failing to reproduce the problem in another browser, I have discovered my own answer. I want to leave this here for other folks who encounter this issue.

> The problem is in how you tell your browser to render MathJax.

If you right-click on some maths, you will see the MathJax settings menu. Under `Math Settings > Math Renderer` you can change how your browser renders MathJax.

[image: Showing the MathJax settings]

Here is a graphical breakdown of three of the options. `HTML-CSS` works best for me, as it renders properly, and I can select the text. `Fast HTML` renders mhchem poorly (but works okay on other maths), but still allows the text to be selected. `SVG` renders very well, but you cannot select it. `MathML` requires a plugin that I see no need to install since one of the other options works.

[image]

Chrome appears to attach these settings to things it remembers about individual sites, which is why mhchem rendered well on main and poorly on meta.