# Why are compound formulae not rendering properly using \ce tag?

Tags: support, mathjax, mhchem

Basically, everywhere I use the \ce tag on chemistry stack exchange, I get wrong formulae. The subscripts are becoming superscripts while the superscripts are becoming subscripts. Is it just me or is this happening to everyone? See the figures below for examples.

[image: wrong formulate of chemical compounds on chemistry stack exchange]

[image: wrong formulate of chemical compounds on chemistry stack exchange]

It seems to be working fine on Chemistry stack exchange meta. For example, $\ce{NaHCO3}$, $\ce{CO2}$, etc.

Update 1: I checked using a different browser and it seems to be working fine.

Update 2: I restarted the computed and the problem is **not** fixed.

Comment: MathJax is rendered on the client site, i.e. your browser or computer, and settings are usually stored as a per site entry. Related and possibly a duplicate: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2853/4945

Answer (score 3):

*Unselect Collapsible Math* under the *Accessibility* option that shows when you *right-click a math equation*.

#### Solution

**Step 1:** Right-Click Math Equation.

**Step 2:** Select Accessibility.

**Step 3:** Unselect Collapsible Math.

**Step 4:** Reload Page.

Comment: So that means this feature has nothing to do with the preferred browser?

Comment: @Proscionexium yes, it is just that if you change this particular setting in any browser, it starts messing with the formatting. I tried changing the setting on the other browser, and the same "bug" appeared. Well, it is not really a bug, rather a feature I still don't understand.

Comment: Please do not use MathJax to format text.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン thank you for the suggestion. I have incorporated the changes.

Comment: @ananta For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration [SE meta - formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) // [SE meta -  tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)  // [Advanced formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know)