# Chemistry stackexchange community should exclude students from its description

Tags: discussion

Being a student, after I study a topic and google its collaterals, I felt this is the community where I can ask any entry level question whether to get guidance or specific questions, whether it is homework, post test, research or for the sake of getting a deeper understanding.
However, it seems that this community deliberately underestimate such questions. The answers are usually with a sarcastic tone, worse is questions are simply closed for no reasons do not cover the students' scope!
If this community cannot tolerate students, I suggest excluding this entity from the community description, if it is related to the guidelines, I suggest to change guidelines to suite students scopes.
However; keeping shutting down students won't help the q&a purpose that this community established upon.
I hope that my voice find its echo to improve this community.

Comment: Some people here either downvote with a passion or perform no action.

Comment: If you do choose to ask a question, please [format your question properly](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88) and [adhere to the guidelines](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Most homework questions are closed because they are ambiguous ([eg](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142507/how-can-major-product-be-less-than-47-in-meta-nitro-aniline)) or they display no effort from the asker ([eg](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142513/how-to-get-2-butanol-from-3-4-dimethylhex-e-en))..

Comment: .. Good homework questions are answered, examples [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94620/in-what-way-could-benzoin-give-tollens-test?rq=1), [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125224/peptide-bond-formation-involving-side-chains-of-charged-amino-acids) and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80448/thermal-stability-of-alkali-metal-hydrides-and-carbonates).

Comment: Re. your most recent question, I think it got closed because it is not entirely clear what conditions you are asking about. Much of your post is worded in a way that suggests "how do alkenes react with diols", indicating literally any reagent, but all the screenshots are asking about oxymercuration. So, do you want a generic answer (which is genuinely too broad and will be re-closed, as there are thousands of different reagent combinations that could be added) or a specific answer (already given in the comments)? If the latter, I would not hesitate to reopen.

Comment: That is just one question, though, and you didn't even mention it, so I don't know if that's what you're upset about. In general I downvoted this as I don't agree with your argument. Even your other questions seem to have received reasonable replies, as far as I can tell, unless you want to point something specifically out for me to look at.

Comment: @orthocresol you are disconnecting the community from its newcomers, I was not talking about my questions here. Please go around and check other students' questions, you can easily see that all of their questions were downvoted or closed! if anything, it means that your system and rules deliberately shutting off students, you might consider not to accept any question from students or change your rules here to be more welcoming and more understanding. You can also run some statistics and see for yourself.

Comment: @orthocresol  It's ok to be expert and don't look from other perspective, but it is not ok to shut off a whole segment just because it is not aligning with some rules that were agreed upon long time ago and are nonconforming with current situations. To be honest, for me, I found it trust worthy to ask question on StackEx because I find it consistent with resources, and enriches my knowledge, you can see that I always ask for reference and source as follow up question, this way I contribute by making sure a  robust answers are provided by this community when it comes to trustworthy answer.

Comment: @orthocresol And what's with the downvote for the question itself, I can see that you may want to downvote an answer because it might be wrong or nonrelevant, but the question!

Comment: On meta, upvotes and downvotes merely signify agreement and disagreement respectively.

Comment: @orthocresol that's simply not true, one of my questions triggered a delay for two days of not allowing to ask any question on ChemEx!  and just because it was downvoted! and it stated this in the warning message and it even said that my account might be blocked if I get more downvotes! how is that merely signifying agreement and disagreement!

Comment: Maybe I am not being clear enough, sorry. Do you know the distinction between [main site](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com) and [meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com)? I downvoted *this* question that you posted *on meta*, because I disagree with it, and downvotes on meta simply mean that I disagree with what you said. I didn't downvote any of your questions *on the main site*. Downvotes on the main site certainly mean something more than disagreement, but I cannot speak for any of the other people who voted on your questions there.

Comment: I notice you originally posted this on main, and that it got moved to meta for you. So maybe this article will help to clarify the difference. See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @user432797 same condition with me. Even if I post good questions, it gets downvoted especially  on CHEM.SE. this is not the site for asking high school questions and the description or tour of chem SE creates an illusion. Some users are good like matt_black and other which cleared my concept. But most community users are bad and deliberately downvote which does a bad impact for newcomers. Make sure moderators and others that since I am telling the truth which most can't tolerate, DON'T delete this comment.

Comment: What makes SE sites special is the set of high quality Qs/As, which is based on following given rules.  That is why people come to Se to fetch some knowledge. But coming, the often do not follow these rules. There is no point in excluding students. But there is the point in teaching them that if they come to a new place ( country, people neighborhood, household, internet community etc.), it is expected them to accommodate by learning and following the local rules. Many newcomers are not aware of such rules, or worse, do not bother to find and follow them.

Comment: @Liang A question may be even very good and still in violation of rules. It may already have very good answers in textbooks or multiple education oriented sites.  I often tell newcomers to think about a question for at least an hour and search thoroughly for possible answers before asking. As writing answers, that were written in textbooks and multiple internet sites many times is rather  wasting of human resources. It may happen you would hesitate to answer a very similar question for nth time, because the user does not bother with searching even within the scope of the same site.

Comment: The problem is, whenever you ask a question that lacks extensive research, this expends time and resources for chemistry experts and moderators. Formulating well-informed questions and answers is a form of respect.

Answer (score 14):

I feel I can kinda answer this question. I was a high school student not too long ago and asked dozens of well received questions exclusively related to high school Chemistry. I even got the [Inquisitive](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges/91/inquisitive?userid=5026) badge, but before I got to Socratic badge I left high school :(

To start with, this community is not built with any particular community (like high school students) in mind. Questions are solely voted upon based on their quality. To a very large degree, it does not matter if you're a high school student or a professional chemist or even a non-chemist. If you have a question in mind, you can post it here.

Anyway, I can understand your frustration, and it's common to new users. I looked at your four questions posted so far and they are ... okay. There's at least a couple of red flags: 1. bad quality image posted via phone 2. discussing multiple questions in the same single post. Even the question on diol with alkene, to me and you it seems a straightforward question with an undisputed answer, but the professional chemists would know that its probably a lot more complicated, which is why it got close voted.

I understand that these questions could be edited by a veteran here to make them better, and I used to do such edits when I was active, but not everyone has enough free time to do edits or teach the newcomers step-by-step what the rules are. Understanding a new question and posting an answer to it is already quite involving, so any more than that is asking for a lot more of free volunteer time.

Most confusion for newcomers arises because [this site is a Q&A site, not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums).  The questions here are generally specific, and they are to build a reservoir of quality question-answer pool, not to have a discussion. A general rule of thumb is that if you want to have discussion around ideas or "to get guidance" (as you said), it's best to not post here, but on other Chemistry forums. However, if you have a concrete question in mind, you can surely post here and get it answered.

It's not to say that the system is perfect, as sometimes good stuff gets close voted too, but overall this is a system that all StackExchange sites are born with, and it's how it works. Many people do get their questions answered here, so if you just wander around here for some time, you'll get the hang of what kind of content generally gets a positive reception, and then you can start posting in the same spirit too. Good luck!