# Creation of a LinkedIn Page for the Chemistry StackExchange community

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I was wondering whether a company page for Chemistry StackExchange can be created on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/). Maybe this could be beneficial to the regular members of our community, from highly-reputed contributors to moderators who can list the same under their professional experience. It could probably benefit some of us in the long run, especially since no monetary remuneration is involved in answering questions and maintaining the site. Listing such experiences could be presented as a good management stint and representation of subject-matter expertise.

I don't know who would have the authority to create such a page, but still just throwing it out there for people better suited to answer that. A precedent for such an initiative has already been set, as [StackOverflow](https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow/) has already made such a page. You can also see many people listed as "Contributors", " Managers" and "Moderators" under the employees of said page.

Comment: SO is a company, Chemistry.se is not... so... I don't know. And I'm not sure it's a good idea... we'll see what them others say.

Comment: I made my followup post https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/chemistry-se-on-your-cv-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-other-professional-avenues I didn't want to post it around Christmas, because there's always a huge dropoff in activity around then, but here it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very late reply, but I mostly agree with Martin's comment. "Stack Overflow" in this case refers to the company, not the Q&A website; consequently, it makes sense to have a LinkedIn page.

I can't actually see the LinkedIn profiles, but I assume that these are employees of SO, not just contributors in the sense of people who post answers. (The employees include so-called *Community Managers*, whom you may have met before: their role is to act as a bridge between the user base and the company.)

More broadly speaking, this ties into the question of whether we should have Chem.SE experience listed on a CV (résumé) or the like, which is one that has come up several times in my time here. (LinkedIn is basically an online CV...?) I originally wrote quite a bit of text about this, but I think this would be an interesting discussion to be had separately, so I'll ask a new question. I hope that you will also find whatever answers I get to be useful in this particular case too.

Comment: orthocresol i have a general doubt. Isn't  the members of SE community very inactive (leaving you guys). They just ask and go never bother to answer others, Do you know any reason?

Comment: I just came from physics SE community

Comment: @Anonymous You mean that lots of people ask questions, but few people answer? I think that's quite normal anywhere, though. A typical school (in real life) has lots of students and few teachers. Are you asking specifically about Chemistry.SE, or SE in general?

Comment: specifically for chemistry SE

Comment: @Anonymous, Chem has far fewer people than Physics in general.

Comment: yeah I can see it. So why not try to flood it with thoughts? I will try my best :)

Comment: @Anonymous most of them are one-timers. They just post the question and never bother to return back to check if there are any answers. Sometimes it bothers me that you have written a detailed answer only to be "not" looked by OP, let alone accepting it. It has occurred to me previously and I have decided that if OP is enthusiastic enough to seek for an answer (based on the comment activity), I will deliver it accordingly. My perspective is to value one's time and effort before sharing knowledge to others.

Comment: @NilayGhosh indeed true. if someone like me starts answering the unanswered questions they downvote it anonymously(not fault for my username). I tried my best aand answered 4 to 5 questions and even tried ofboosting the platform but they are downvoting(that discourages me(not even a single upvote).

Comment: @Anonymous Well, anon downvotes can't be helped. It is a nuisance. You need to keep in mind: 1) Understand the question first, if you don't understand, then your answer will be wrongly interpreted and you will receive downvotes. If you have queries, write that as a comment 2)Your answer should be self-contained and self-explanatory. Cross-question should also be addressed. Flaw in answer generate downvotes 3)Construct your answer in a neat and clean way. Organize your answer with proper punctuations and para-breaks. Avoid long sentence.....

Comment: (Cont...)Keep your post short and simple, if OP requires further information, extend your answer only then 4)Learn [proper chemical formatting and markup](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). It will take time but you'll learn eventually.5) Use proper source for your information and avoid plagiarism. 6)Address feedback and comments. Learn to acknowledge criticism. 7) Have fun. Good luck!!

Comment: I can say that in Chemistry grad school applications, I've seen Chem.SE mentioned in people's materials. Obviously, it's one way to stand out. :-)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Really? That's exactly the kind of stuff I want to use Chem.SE experience for, in applying for higher studies and internships. I guess it maybe relevant for mentioning after all :)

Comment: @YusufHasan I do use my flair on profiles.. it makes a neat little HTML embed.