# No answers for a question

Tags: support

[Temperature dependence of Aldol condensations](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/178273/temperature-dependence-of-aldol-condensations)

This question has got no answers in SE earlier. I had altogether changed my question as it was a duplicate. And I was not able to post a new question. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150376/discussion-on-question-by-harikrishnan-m-no-answers-for-a-question); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are patiently waiting for an answer, do some of your own research. Also, you can look at related questions, and see how other contributors formulate them and share their research (or their attempts at figuring out the problem using what they already know).

This is a site that does not charge money (it might cost you some time, though). Some questions don't get any answers, some questions get answers that might not be useful, and some questions get answers that might teach you a thing or two.

> Can anyone please guide me?

Slow down. Try to post less rather than more, and try to spend more time before you post so that when you post it aligns with how the site works best. I'm assuming you have already read [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour), [that](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help), and [those](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). If you want to have a chat, use the chat.