# Why allow non-chemistry dimension analysis?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

This question is not being closed on Chemistry, despite it having nothing to do with chemistry: [Answer Conversion Problem Numerically in Kilometers Per Hour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/answer-conversion-problem-numerically-in-kilometers-per-hour)

jonsca, whom I have much respect for, had said that questions like this are not being closed because chemistry textbooks have such questions. But given that we are NOT a homework site without effort, why should we allow off-topic questions? If you want to ask a dimension analysis question on Stackexchange.Chemistry, why not ask a chemistry question?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this here. :)  I have closed my Meta question as a duplicate of this one.  I wasn't sure if anyone was going to post one, so I made one anyway.

Comment: @jonsca: No problem, you raise an issue I had not considered. Let's address it!

Comment: We get have a similar problem at [cs.se] SE. Since computer scientists tend to do quite a bit of programming, we get a lot of programming questions. Most of these are purely about programming and we're pretty aggressive about closing them and migrating any good ones to [SO]. That seems to work pretty well: the bad questions get put on hold and the good ones get punted to a more appropriate palce.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions about dimensional analysis that do not refer to a specific chemistry question or problem should be closed. They can be migrated to mathematics.se as they allow such kinds of questions in their [homework policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). For example:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/929376
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/920980
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/917007

The linked question in the OP's post does not have any relation to chemistry whatsoever.

On another note, the scope of chemistry.se is more comparable to physics.se and their [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714), as they state in their initial summary:

> It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on

Now I admit, that our own [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/141/4945) is a little less strict, which I think is also a good thing. Most of the time there is a conceptual problem behind it and it can be useful for generations to come.
However, we also clearly state:

> As a general rule, we do not discourage homework questions, as long as they are related to chemistry.

The conversion from $\mathrm{m/s}$ to $\mathrm{km/h}$ is in my opinion not essentially related to chemistry. I am also of the opinion, that it is not really a type of conceptual question either.

Answer (score 4):

Allow me to answer this question. Chemistry is one of a few sciences where math is immediately applicable at an elementary level. Given this, one could be tempted to ask non-chemistry math questions. We might even be able to answer them. But in the overall context of StackExchange, they seem off-topic given the other SEs available to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Dimensional analysis was something I was first introduced to in a chemistry course, and was revisited later in a physics course. While it is on a fundamental level, just a mathematical technique, if *I* were a student on the cusp of learning dimensional analysis *and* learning it in my chemistry course, it would be frustrating to be told that i came to the wrong site for an answer.

Comment: Doesn't migrating the question to the correct site mitigate the frustration?