# Generally question of answering and deleting of posts

Tags: discussion

I answered to a question to this topic

[Preparation of solution with hydrated molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111574/preparation-of-solution-with-hydrated-molecules)

I got first an comment my answer didnt answer the question.
By a guy namend Felipe S. S Schneider.
I want to answer to his comment but I couldnt, because  I have not much reputations to do.
So I implement it in the answer itself by eding it.
For this crime I got another comment of a other mod called andselisk.
Finally the whole thing is deleted by a third mod Jonsca.

Now the question was answered by giving the whole solution by Mathew Mahindaratne.

In your forum rules we should not give final answers for students who are to lazy to do there home work.

That is the reason I answered in a hidden way. Not with a final answer. The student should ask again, learning by doing.

On other place it is said it should be answered that the asker didnt ask again. What is now right.
The very bad thing is it is not possible to defeat here, because which way is used the messages are blocked or deleted. Iam abot 62 years old and have seen a lot of things in my life but this is realy terrible how it worked here. 
I also dont understand why comment and answer section, voting and reputation is different and why restriction there.

I hope this question will be answered in a good way to understand and not deleted again.

Comment: It sounds like you may be experiencing growing pains, just understand we want content on this site to be higher quality than some other Q&A sites. Don't be discouraged and check out other meta posts.

Answer (score 9):

> I want to answer to his comment but I couldnt, because I have not much reputations to do.

This is not true, you can always comment on your own posts regardless of reputation.

> In your forum rules we should not give final answers for students who are to lazy to do there home work.

This has not been the case for a number of months. We prefer full answers, as outlined in [Hint answers revisited](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/hint-answers-revisited). If there is still a "rule" that says otherwise can you please point me to it so that I can change it?

> The student should ask again, learning by doing.

The full rationale is explained in more detail in the link above, but this is exactly one thing which we want to avoid. Stack Exchange is not a place for one-on-one tutoring and walking through questions step-by-step with long comment discussions. It is not meant as a substitute for a tutorial, office hours, etc.

> The very bad thing is it is not possible to defeat here, because which way is used the messages are blocked or deleted.

Deletion is not *censorship*; we don't have a vested interest in oppressing the masses. It is just that quality control for questions and answers on main site is strict, because we want to maintain standards which encourage thorough, well-researched answers (of which there are many). As outlined in the linked post above, answers that are merely hints are not considered to be answers, and consequently we delete them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer: *"This is not true, you can always comment on your own posts regardless of reputation."* I got still a message that I cannot commend because I am below 50 reputations. *"The full rationale is explained in more detail in the link above, but this is exactly one thing which we want to avoid. Stack Exchange is not a place for one-on-one tutoring and walking through questions step-by-step with long comment discussions. It is not meant as a substitute for a tutorial, office hours, etc."* This enlighted me, it is a total opposit opinion as in other forums. Good to know.

Comment: Are you trying to comment using the same account which posted the answer? All users should be able to comment on their own posts regardless of reputation, cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/312770