# Homework questions which asks for alternate solution

Tags: discussion, homework

I am asking if I can post some homework questions which asks for alternate solutions.

> Why do I need alternate solution?

It's because the solution I have might be too long or I might be wondering if we can solve it using any other rule of chemistry.

> How do we know that you are not making us do your homework?

I will also post my original solution.

So would it be okay if I ask for alternate solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current [Homework Policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange?rq=1) only requires that you show some effort in solving the problem. The reason such obligations are deemed necessary is that 'requiring effort' is one of the best ways to maintain quality and not let it reduce while there's a lot of potential for increasing bad questions.

I imagine such a question, with some elegant phrasing, would surely make for a good and thought-out answer. As long as we're not doing "approach golf", and as long as you have provided your reasoning, I believe you're allowed to ask as many as you want.

Comment: Thanks. I shall/should wait for the responses of other users too.

Comment: Sure. Usually Martin or Jan or other people also have something useful to add to the discussion; I recommend accepting meta posts only when you're sure the discussion needs to be done is *infinitesimal*.

Comment: But in the end, it seems like nobody really likes the questions with homework tag.. :(

Comment: @Manshu I'm pretty sure everyone frequenting the site likes a thought-provoking question. The tag may make bad impressions on some people, but leaving it out when the question should have it is worse.

Comment: @manshu I don't think that is true. A well asked question is a well asked question, even (maybe especially) if it is homework. What people and the format of the site don't like are "check my work" questions, because if it is already solved then the comment might just be: "Yes."